# Replace directory path by manipulating string - Java

Tags: java, string, replace, stringescapeutils

How do i replace the directory path of a string?
The original string is:

```
String fn = "/foo/bar/ness/foo-bar/nessbar.txt";
```

i need the output to look like:

```
/media/Transcend/foo-bar/nessbar.txt
```

I've tried the line below but it doesn't work

```
fn.replaceAll("/foo/bar/ness", "/media/Transcend");
```

Comment: Don't use `replaceAll` if you are not going to use regular expressions, use `replace` which does the same job. But for this problem you just might end up doing `File` objects instead of string manipulation..

Comment: @Tom, you do know that this question is much older than the one you've linked as duplicate, right?

Comment: @alvas And you do know that this isn't important?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forget to rewrite variable:

```
String fn = "/foo/bar/ness/foo-bar/nessbar.txt";
fn = fn.replaceAll("/foo/bar/ness", "/media/Transcend");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
fn = fn.replaceAll("/foo/bar/ness", "/media/Transcend");
```

The [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method returns a new `String` object, leaving the original object unmodified. That's why you need to assign the result somewhere, for example, in the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

replaceAll somehow did not work for me, could not figure out why, i ended up something like this, though it replaces only first part of path.

```
String fn = "C:/foo/bar/ness/foo-bar/nessbar.txt";
Strign r = "C:/foo/bar/ness";
fn = "C:/media/Transcend" + fn.substring(r.length());
```